# Why does from ... import appear to bind to value at import time in Python?

Tags: python

All the Python docs I've read appear to indicate that, side-effects aside, that if you import module A and then reference A.a, you are referencing the same variable as if you wrote "from A import a".

However, that doesn't appear to be the case here and I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using Python 2.6.1.

If I create a module alpha.py:

```
bravo = None

def set_bravo():
  global bravo
  bravo = 1
```

Then create a script that imports the module:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('.'))

import alpha
from alpha import bravo

alpha.set_bravo()
print "Value of bravo is: %s" % bravo
print "Value of alpha.bravo is: %s" % alpha.bravo
```

Then I get this output:

```
Value of bravo is: None
Value of alpha.bravo is: 1
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from ... import ...` *always* binds immediately, even if a previous `import` only imported the module/package.

**EDIT:**

Contrast the following:

```
import alpha

alpha.set_bravo()

from alpha import bravo

print "Value of bravo is: %s" % bravo
print "Value of alpha.bravo is: %s" % alpha.bravo
```

Comment: Ah. I thought 'import' imported variable names from a module into the local namespace, but it sounds like it binds the same name in the local namespace to the *value* of the imported variable.

I'm not sure if that's lame or I'm too lame to realize that it's not.

Comment: Correct. Python doesn't have "variables" per se, only "names".

Answer (score 0):

python -m dis bravo.py execute that to see what's happening to your code during compilation.
I found this blog useful in understanding what's happening under the hood. http://late.am/post/2012/03/26/exploring-python-code-objects